# Prove a rotating window shade won't break my window when raised to a specific height.

Tags: geometry

I have a large lampshade that covers my window to block out sunlight. It has a metal rod sewn in at the bottom to weigh it down, but it's aluminum, so it can rock in wind. We recently had a flash flood in the area with extremely heavy winds, and since the lamp shade was oscillating like crazy, I feared it would break the window, so I furled (pulled the draw string to roll it up) the shade high enough so that it couldn't rotate enough for the rods to possibly hit the window. So we come to my question:

*If we treat the shade as two identical rotating pendulums on an axis with a rod connecting them, how can I find the minimum height such that the shade itself won't rotate enough for the rod's ends to hit to hit and possibly break my window?*

I would like for this to be as general as possible, but I don't know any structural analysis in a physics sense, or where to start aside from drawing a few hypothesis based on some pictures. This is most likely a linear algebra problem since the rotational matrix came to mind, which is why I came to math stackexchange seeking some assistance to get me started. Essentially, I need to know what math is needed to solve this problem.

If you need any clarification or if this question is fundamentally flawed in any way, please do not hesitate to ask.

Edit: To make things a little simpler, I do not want the ends of the rod to touch the window at all, so I don't need to consider the amount of force needed to break the window.

[image]

Comment: Supplying a diagram would be extremely helpful

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to post images...

Comment: Horribly mistagged. Not sure I can think of good ones :-(

Answer (score 1):

Could you (standing on a ladder, perhaps) lift the rod and move it so that it contacts the window?  If you can, the wind can too.